# Are there reusable CLAs?

Tags: contributor-agreements

Many FOSS projects require [Contributor License Agreements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contributor_License_Agreement) (CLA) for all contributors. Even though we have many common FOSS software licenses, it seems that these projects have to create their own CLAs.

Are there any standard/generic/reusable CLAs?

Answer (score 7):

From [Opensource FAQ](http://opensource.org/faq#contributor-agreements):-

> For more about contributor agreements in general, and some examples, see [civiccommons.org/Contributor_Agreements](http://wiki.civiccommons.org/Contributor_Agreements/). See also the [Project Harmony](http://harmonyagreements.org), "...a community-centered group focused on contributor agreements for free and open source software (FOSS)."

- At [How to Accept Code and Documentation Contributions Legally](http://wiki.civiccommons.org/Contributor_Agreements/#how-to-accept-code-and-documentation-contributions-legally) you can find **CLA examples**
- You can get [Harmony Contributor Agreement Templates](http://harmonyagreements.org/agreements.html) in odt, html or pdf format. Or from [Agreement Selector](http://selector.harmonyagreements.org/) you can preview and get Example CLAs

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple great sites for that. In both you answer a few very simple questions and you get your templates with standard clauses and in several formats:

- [Project Harmony](http://www.harmonyagreements.org/index.html)
- [ContributorAgreements.org](http://contributoragreements.org/)

Answer (score -1):

And of course the Linux http://developercertificate.org/ the simplest and best of all IMHO

Comment: It's unclear if that certificate can be used freely by other projects. Its contents include the line "Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim copies of this license document, but changing it is not allowed."

Comment: Also, it's not really a CLA, but rather just a certificate of origin.

Comment: This is a generic document, that is not project specific.... and for all practical purpose, everyone treats this the same they treat a CLA, so the downvote is unwarranted or the downvoter is uninformed from the FOSS ways IMHO.